# I have some doubts with few lines of code AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Where I work we have an angularjs project that I need to modify but I can't understand totally this code:

```
app.controller("complementsController", function($scope, $rootScope, $mdSidenav, $timeout, $localStorage, $window) {
    $scope.storage = $localStorage;
    $scope.arrayCubiert = $scope.storage.cocinaCubiert.split("-");
    $scope.tipoCubiert = $scope.arrayCubiert[1];
    $scope.return = function() {
        $window.history.back()
    };
    $scope.configurations = [{
        logo: "some-logo",
        val: 1
    }];
    "CUE" != $scope.tipoCubiera && "CUF" != $scope.tipoCubiert && "CUS" != $scope.tipoCubiert || $scope.configurations.push({
        logo: "fiss-logo",
        val: 2
    });
    "CUE" == $scope.tipoCubiert && $scope.configurations.push({
        logo: "grafett-essence",
        val: 3
    });
    $scope.opcionTitle = "EhapeAL", $scope.opcionImg = [ ["EAL.png", "EhapeAL AL"] ];
    $scope.opcionBtn = 1, $timeout(function() {
        $mdSidenav("sidebar").toggle().then(function() {})
    }, 500);
```

Specifically what I do not understand is:

**"CUE" != $scope.tipoCubierta && "CUF" != $scope.tipoCubierta && "CUS" != $scope.tipoCubierta || $scope.configuraciones.push({
        logo: "fisso-logo",
        val: 2
    }),**

this is a kind of shorthand conditional??? If so, as would be made of "traditional" way.

Comment: This is in dire need of some indentation to make it readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MDN about [logical opereator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators) :

> *Short-circuit evaluation*
>
> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested
> for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> **false && anything is short-circuit evaluated to false.**
>
> **true || anything is short-circuit evaluated to true.**
>
> The rules of logic guarantee that these evaluations are always correct. Note that the
> anything part of the above expressions is not evaluated, so any side
> effects of doing so do not take effect.

So the "traditional" way for above code is:

```
if(!("CUE" != $scope.tipoCubierta && "CUF" != $scope.tipoCubierta && "CUS" != $scope.tipoCubierta)){
     $scope.configuraciones.push({ logo: "fisso-logo", val: 2 })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that's not something related with AngularJS is just javascript
if you put something like:

```html
4 != 1 && 4 != 2 && 4 != 3 || console.log("hello world")
```

it's the same that

```html
if(4 != 1 && 4 != 2) {
 if( !(4 != 3){ //console is only executed when the 3rd condition is FALSE because is an OR
  console.log("hello world");
  }
}

//remember that saying foo == 1 && foo == 2 || foo == 3 it's the same as   foo == 1 && (foo == 2 || foo =3)
```

hope it helps